# How to convert a epub textbook into TeX file?

Tags: epub

I just bought a textbook in epub format and my E-reader is having trouble rendering it because of all the equations. So, I converted the epub file to pdf and I am able to use it but the font is too tiny.
Is there a way to convert the epub file to tex file?
I intent to use the tex file to create a new pdf that would have font size that is readable on my tiny E-reader screen.

Comment: not really you can (if the licence permits it, which it propbably doesn't) copy the text and then mark up the tex commands by hand. You may find that mathpix can OCR the pages and generate tex markup for the math.

Comment: Many (most?) pdf readers have a "scale" option.  Have you looked for that?  (Obviously, on a small screen, this would require a *lot* of scrolling.)